# Count only the first two levels of the multilevel menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `menu` with columns: `id`, `value`, `id_parent`.

In model:

```
public function getMenu()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM menu";
    return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

In controller:

```
public function adminNavMenu()
{
    $this->data['menu'] = $this->model->getMenu();

    $result = [];
    foreach ($this->data['menu'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['id_parent'] == 0) {
            $result[$value['id']] = $value;
        } else {
            $result[$value['id_parent']]['children'][] = $value;
        }
     }
}
```

But it count only the first two levels of the multilevel menu. I tried to apply a cycle or recursion, but I can not...

Help me, please, correct mistaces.

Original menu view:

```
Menu1
Menu2->
       Menu2-1
       Menu2-2
       Menu2-3->
                Menu2-3-1
```

Invalid output after `var_dump($result)`;

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [value] => Menu1
            [id_parent] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [value] => Munu2
            [id_parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [value] => Menu2-1
                            [id_parent] => 2
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [value] => Menu2-2
                            [id_parent] => 2
                        ) 
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [value] => Menu2-3
                            [id_parent] => 2
                        )
                )
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [value] => Menu2-3-1
                            [id_parent] => 5
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: post your output, like errors, etc.

Comment: I post my output

Answer (score 0):

From below code you can get some what idea :

```
<?php
function get_menu_tree($parent_id) 
{
    global $con;
    $menu = "";
    $sqlquery = " SELECT * FROM menu where id_parent='" .$parent_id . "' "; // put your query
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
           $menu .="<li>".$row['value']."</a>";

           $menu .= "<ul>".get_menu_tree($row['id'])."</ul>"; //call  recursively

           $menu .= "</li>";

    }

    return $menu;
} 
?>
```

Call this function :

```
<?php echo get_menu_tree(0);//start from root menus having parent id 0 ?>
```

Comment: Where is `status` comming from?